# Turn on Bluetooth on an iMac without a keyboard or mouse?

Tags: keyboard, imac, bluetooth

I have a 2015 iMac, that I use with a Magic Keyboard and a Magic Trackpad. Today I was changing some settings and accidentally turned off Bluetooth, disconnecting my peripherals.

Is there any way to get Bluetooth re-enabled without a USB keyboard/mouse? I don't have either a wired mouse or keyboard. Could I remote in from my iPhone somehow?

If I have to get them, will a wired keyboard be sufficient to enable Bluetooth without a mouse?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Magic Keyboard/Trackpad as wired devices by using a Lightning-to-USB cable (like the one from your iPhone).

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way to get Bluetooth re-enabled without a USB keyboard/mouse?

If you have accidentally turned off Bluetooth thereby disconnecting Apple Magic Keyboard and Magic Mouse/Magic Trackpad, simply hard reboot your Mac by pressing and holding the power button.

Then restart your Mac, and it will trigger the wizard for connecting keyboard and mouse which will in turn, enable Bluetooth.

*Do note that hard rebooting may not be the desirable approach as it may cause you to lose data.*

> Could I remote in from my iPhone somehow?

If you already have screen sharing configured, it's possible to use any of the various VNC apps available on the App Store to remote control your iMac and thereby easily turn on Bluetooth.

> If I have to get them, will a wired keyboard be sufficient to enable Bluetooth without a mouse?

Yes. Open System Preferences, and use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> to highlight the search field. Now enter *keyboard shortcuts* and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. You'll be presented with keyboard shortcuts preference pane. Now use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd> (You may need to use the <kbd>fn</kbd> key), to select **All controls** setting.

[image]

Now switch to search field again using the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> and type *Bluetooth*. Use the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key to move focus to Turn Bluetooth On button and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> to toggle.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To add something here for anyone that happens to google their way in here and, like me, uses the Adobe Creative Cloud and has also turned off the cmd-space shortcut for spotlight... My keyboard connects via USB but I have a bluetooth mouse.

Use cmd-tab to select Finder.
Then cmd-U to open Utilities.
Use arrows to navigate to Bluetooth File Exchange.
Cmd-O (that's oh, not zero) to open this while selected -- I was furiously hitting enter to no avail
It should detect that your bluetooth is off and prompt you to hit enter to enable

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a friend of hard reboot, which can cause trouble in macOS. I think using a Lightning-to-USB cable is a good solution.

"Could I remote in from my iPhone?"

**Yes you can!**

For other problems, when macOS stalled I'm using Terminus on iPad where I configured the settings for my iMac.

https://apps.apple.com/de/app/termius-ssh-client/id1176074088?l=en&mt=12

**I'm using Terminus for free.**

Simply using:

**sudo shutdown -h now**

or

**sudo reboot**
does the job.[image].
[image]

[image]

Greetings

Answer (score -2):

After rebooting , nothing happened.   But, I found an answer!  If your wifi is still working,  connect a wifi enabled mouse and it works!

Comment: Can you add a link to a product description of a wifi-enabled mouse?